# BGE: How to display random list of text in game with python?

Tags: python, game-engine

Perhaps there is no function like this in blender, but how do I use python to display text randomly from an array? Essentially, during a loading screen I want to be able to scrub through different "tips" randomly using python; these tips will be displayed in a text-box inside the game. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ah this is a simple python problem.

if I understand correctly all you have to do is

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,len(tips)-1))
```

or

```
import random
random.choice(tips)
```

of course actually displaying them in the game itself is possible, just slightly more complicated.

also next time please post a python question in a python thread.

since this is technically a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Comment: Thank you; however, I reworked my code a little using your hint about random.choice instead of random.shuffle. This is my current code:   'import bge
import bpy
import random
import time

tips = ["Press space to switch between perspectives!", "In 3d mode? Press 'e' to jump!", "Eat more veggies!", "Watch the timer!", "Does anybody actually read these things?"]
count = 0

while count == 0:
    count = count + .5
    for i in tips:
        bpy.data.objects["Textbox"].data.body = random.choice(tips)
        time.sleep(.5)  
    if count == 5.5:
        count = 0'

Comment: Formatting in comment form sucks... sorry. It doesn't work when I hit play, only in object mode and it iterates through the list everytime I end the game engine. How do I make it work in the game engine was the question, which is the only reason I posted it here/ I do apologise for the misunderstanding and inconvenience!

Comment: Ah, I don't believe your code is the issue, you probably have an actuator with both skips down, tic those off and it should work. But now I'm just taking shots in the dark because I don't have your .blend. -- or to have it display something different every time, change the skip counter.